# How to introduce support for command line options in a script that is written to use positional arguments?

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expression, arguments

I have a script that is currently used with positional arguments, like this:

```bsh
./script.sh fname lname address
```

I want to also support ordinary command line options when I call this script, so that I may skip arguments I don't want to give:

```bsh
./script.sh -f fname -a address
```

`fname` is the only mandatory parameter.

For historical reasons and automation, the script needs to be backwards compatible.

My best guess so far has been to look for the  `-f`  string (surrounded by spaces),

- if found, process the flags
- if not, process sequentially

```bsh
flags='(\ |^)-f\ '
if [[ $* =~ $flags ]]; then
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
    name="$1"
    case "$name" in
        -f)
            shift
            fname=$1
            ;;
        -l)
            shift
            lname=$1
            ;;
        -a)
            shift
            address=$1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
else
    fname=${1}
    lname=${2}
    address=${3}
fi
```

But here, I need to use a regular expression for checking for options, which can be unreliable.

Is there a native way to combine command line options and positional arguments?

Comment: Extend the `case` statement to detect non-option arguments or unknown options. and break from the `while` loop. After the loop check if any of `fname`, `lname` or `address` has already been assigned a value. Or use an additional variable to record that you found a known option. Generally, before accessing `$1` etc. I suggest to check `$#`. You could also use the `getopts` or `getopt` utility, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16483119/10622916

Comment: `Is there a native way to combine flagged and indexed arguments?` "native"? You just do it - just remove the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement ordinary command line parsing using `getopts`.  If that parsing is triggered at all, set a flag to keep track of this fact.  After the standard `getopts` loop, if the flag hasn't been set, fall back to the old behavior.

In the code below, the flag is the variable `new_behavior`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# As written now, this should run without issues with
# /bin/sh too (there are no bash-isms in this code).

unset address
unset fname
unset lname

new_behavior=false

while getopts 'a:f:l:' opt; do
        new_behavior=true

        case $opt in
                a)
                        address=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                f)
                        fname=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                l)
                        lname=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo 'Error in command line parsing' >&2
                        exit 1
        esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

if ! "$new_behavior"; then
        # Fall back on old behavior.

        fname=$1;       shift
        lname=$1;       shift
        address=$1;     shift
fi

if [ -z "$fname" ]; then
        echo 'Missing mandatory argument "fname"' >&2
        exit 1
fi

# The rest is unimportant to the actual command line parsing code
# and only here for your information and for debugging.

printf 'fname="%s", lname="%s", address="%s"\n' \
        "$fname" "$lname" "$address"

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        printf 'Extra argument: "%s"\n' "$@"
fi
```

The new behavior is triggered as soon as a user provides an option as the first argument to the script.  It does not matter whether the option is valid or not.

Testing old behavior:

```
$ ./script eff ell addr
fname="eff", lname="ell", address="addr"
```

```
$ ./script eff ell addr "hello world"
fname="eff", lname="ell", address="addr"
Extra argument: "hello world"
```

```
$ ./script eff
fname="eff", lname="", address=""
```

```
$ ./script
Missing mandatory argument "fname"
```

```
$ ./script eff -l ell
fname="eff", lname="-l", address="ell"
```

Testing new behavior:

```
$ ./script -a addr -l ell -f eff
fname="eff", lname="ell", address="addr"
```

```
$ ./script -a addr -f eff "hello world"
fname="eff", lname="", address="addr"
Extra argument: "hello world"
```

```
$ ./script -f eff "hello world"
fname="eff", lname="", address=""
Extra argument: "hello world"
```

```
$ ./script -l eff "hello world"
Missing mandatory argument "fname"
```

```
$ ./script -f eff -- -l ell -f "eff again"
fname="eff", lname="", address=""
Extra argument: "-l"
Extra argument: "ell"
Extra argument: "-f"
Extra argument: "eff again"
```

(Note in last example that where the non-option extra arguments are delimited from the options with `--`, neither `-l` nor the second `-f` are options.)

Answer (score 0):

So why do you use that `if` at all? Just check the arguments.

```
flaggiven=0
# This is very unsafe - use `getopt` or `getopts`. `shift` can fail - should be checked for errors.
while (($#)); do
    case "$1" in
    -f) fname=$2; flaggiven=1; shift; ;;
    -l) lname=$2; flaggiven=1; shift; ;;
    -a) address=$2; flaggiven=1; shift; ;;
    *) break;
    esac
    shift
done

if (($# > 0)); then
     if ((flaggiven)); then
        echo "ERROR: you have given -f or -l or -a argument and arguments. One or the other, not both!"
        exit 1
     fi
     fname=$1
     lname=$2
     address=$3
else
   if ((!flaggiven)); then
        echo "ERROR: you have to pass -f -l -a flags or pass 3 arguments"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```